# Notice: Undefined variable: title in E:\xampp\htdocs\blog4\new-post.php on line 11

Tags: php, html, mysql

Notice: Undefined variable: title in E:\xampp\htdocs\blog4\new-post.php on line 11

I keep getting this error and also Missing data is appearing before any data is submitted

```
include('db.php');

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

}

if($title && $body){
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES('$title', '$body')");
            if($query){
                echo"Post Added";
                }else{
                echo"error";}
        }else{
            echo"Missing data";
        }
```

Comment: Question title can be more appropriate.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun deprecation process. Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: I need to see **html form** from start to end tag.

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST['submit']` is not set, `$title` will not be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute with

```
if (isset($title, $body)) {
    //....
```

Answer (score 1):

`db.php`:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name_here', 'username', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
?>
```

`new-post.php`:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES (?, ?)');
    $result = $query->execute(array($_POST['title'], $_POST['body']));
    if($result) {
        echo 'Post Added!';
    } else {
        echo 'Database error.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Missing data!';
}
?>
```

---

Please **don't** use `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and are in the deprecation process.

Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo.construct) instead.

PDO also supports prepared statements, which helps avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Initialized the $title with empty like this at the top

```
$title = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for a POST request then check and set your values; If values are not null then do your query, also make your inputs safe else having `'` in your data will cause an error.

```
include('db.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $title = (!empty($_POST['title'])?$_POST['title']:null);
    $body  = (!empty($_POST['body'])?$_POST['body']:null);

    if($title != null && $body != null){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($body)."')");
        if($query){
            $result = "Post Added";
        }else{
            $result = "Error";
        }
    }else{
        $result = "Missing data";
    }

    echo $result;
}
```